# need help to enter the orthogonal sign, the upside down T.

Tags: mathematical-optimization, symbols, education

I have search on Google and never came across any idea how to enter this damn sign. would anyone give me some hint?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need [UpTee](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/character/UpTee.html):

```
UpTee[x, y]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

or

```
x \[UpTee] y
```

or, using the input alias,

```
x ESC uT ESC y
```

> x ⊥ y

Comment: If you're simply trying to reproduce the character in text (any document type), a useful resource is Wikipedia's `List of Unicode characters`. Interestingly, that document lists it as `UpTack` (alternatively `falsum`), but not `UpTee` as @kglr comments. Irregardless, you can locate it visually in their `Mathematical Operators` subsection: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Mathematical_Operators

Comment: `UpTee`?? But that's no fun. I've always wanted to say "There's the perp"